# DrawaerLayout.onDrawerOpened is never called

Tags: android, navigation, listener, drawer

I want to change a textview within my DrawerLayout. So I extend it with my own class. The problem is when I debug this code, the onDrawerOpened is never called, specifically when the Drawer is being opened.

```
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;

    public class MyDrawerLayout extends DrawerLayout implements DrawerLayout.DrawerListener {
    //Context context;

    public MyDrawerLayout(Context c) {
        this(c, null);
    }

    public MyDrawerLayout(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(c, attrs, 0);
    }

    public MyDrawerLayout (Context c, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super (c, attrs, defStyle);
        setDrawerListener(this);
    }

    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {

        LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout)(drawerView.findViewById(R.id.root));
        TextView t = (TextView) (root.findViewById(R.id.textView));
        t.setText(((MainActivity) MainActivity.main_activity).globalScenarioName);
        Snackbar.make(((MainActivity)MainActivity.main_activity).container, "NAVVIEW Open", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show();
    }

    public void  onDrawerSlide (View drawerView, float slide) {

    }

    public void onDrawerClosed (View drawerView) {

    }

    public  void onDrawerStateChanged (int newState) {}
}
```

The activity_main.xml layout looks standard:

```
<net.mycom.myproject.widget.MyDrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</net.mycom.myproject.widget.MyDrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your constructor you should call `setDrawerListener(this)`, to register your class as listener, since it is implmenting `DrawerLayout.DrawerListener`

```
public MyDrawerLayout(Context c) {
    this(c, null);
}

public MyDrawerLayout(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(c, attrs, 0);
}

public MyDrawerLayout (Context c, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super (c, attrs, defStyle);
    setDrawerListener(this);
}
```

you don't to keep a reference to the context. View has the method `getContext()`

Comment: UPD Just did according to your advice -- still onDrawerOpened is not called.

Comment: update your question and show me the changes you made to your code

Comment: how do you know that is not called? Is it possible that you are calling `setDrawerListener` also from the outside?

Comment: First, the TextView is not modified. Second, in the debug mode the stop point is never reached. I learnt about the method setDrawerListener() from you, so it is unique. UPD The constructor is executed, BTW.

Comment: there is no reason why the listener shouldn't be called, if you are not overriding the reference and you are using `MyDrawerLayout` in your layout. Post more code.

Comment: Thank you, Blackbelt, for your patience. I found some old code in the onCreate:                               MyDrawerLayout drawer = (MyDrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

Comment: `drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);` is overriding the other `setDrawerListener`. You can just one.

Comment: Yes, I see this. It's a spill over code from the Android Studio template.